# PHP: How to detect direct requests of external visitors?

Tags: php, jquery, dialog, http-referer

I would like to detect/prevent/forward direct requests of external visitors. Some scripts should only be displayed in a jQuery dialog.

My current code:

```
<script>
$(".dialog").click(function() {
    // some code for validation
    // ...
    $("#dialog").load(this.href).dialog();
});
</script>    

<a href="http://domain.de/path/to/form/" class="dialog">Open me in a dialog</a>
```

That works fine BUT if I open this link in a new tab/window (e.g. by clicking the middle mouse-button), the form will be displayed "naked".

In this case I would like to forward the user to the refered page, e.g.:

```
if ($requester != $server) {
    header ("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
}
```

How can I detect $requester and $server? I don't want to block every script or a whole directory!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to what @Dharman suggested
jQuery adds a header to all its ajax request called `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` so you could simply check against this header in the `$_SERVER` global array.

Example:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])
{
    // check if the request is ajax 
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
          $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest' ){
          // ajax content loading
    }

    header ("Location: index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])
{
    header ("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: This will not work if a form is posted through get request method

Comment: @shawndreck: thanks for your notice! But it's just to avoid the user gets the unstyled form.

Answer (score 1):

I have those values coming in on a external request:

> [HTTP_HOST] => 104.219.42.237
>
> [HTTP_REFERER] => http:// someurl.com

So, my solution is :

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) !== FALSE) {

    echo 'same origin/request';

} else {

   echo 'different origin/request';
}
```

...

...

...

The Reason that previous solutions did not work !

In My case: 
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ==  'http:// someurl.com'

while 
 $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] does not contains 'http' nor 'https'

So,

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])
```

won't match

The other answer

```
if( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $your_Server_IP_Address)
```

will not work on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the remote address for the IP address of the request sender using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. Do it like this:

```
if( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $your_Server_IP_Address)
     echo 'From same server';
else
     echo 'from different server';
```

Another possible idea solution could be to use a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce):

- When displaying the form, put a hidden input field in it, containing
  a random value
- At the same time, store that random value into the session that
  correspond to the user.
- When the form is submitted, check that the hidden field has the same
  value as the one that's stored in session.

If those two values are not the same, refuse to use the submitted data.

Note : this idea is often used to help fight against CSRF -- and integrated in the "Form" component of some Frameworks (Zend Framework, for instance).

Comment: The user's browser requests the form in BOTH instances, comparing IP addresses is useless.

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR represents the address from which the request came which is going to be different if the users of the site are not on the same localhost as the server

Comment: So when the user's browser requests the php file he can do the check rite.